# Get and display the multiple choice that have been selected

Tags: php, mysql, html

So this is my form that let the users select input from a table :

```
echo"Please select questions to analyze : ";
$qsq = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT question_text FROM questions ");
echo "<form name='whatever' action='next.php' method='get'>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qsq))
{

echo"<input type='checkbox' name='choice' value='" . $row['question_id'] . "' /> ". $row['question_text'] . '<br />';

}

echo"<br>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='submit' /></form>";
```

In the next.php where the form directs to,how can i display the selected one ? should i make an array or any better suggestions ?Please help me i am a beginner in this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo"<input type='checkbox' name='choice[]' value='" . $row['question_id'] . "' /> ". $row['question_text'] . '<br />';
```

Add `[]` to the name of checkbox.

This will post the check box as an array.

```
$_POST['choice'] = array('questionId1', 'questionId2');
```

Comment: Hi,so what should be the somevalues ?

Comment: these will be the array of values of checkboxes you have selected.

Comment: So how can i display the array ?

Comment: by applying loop or  using `echo implode(' ', $_POST['choice']);`